# PHP find file extension of match filename

Tags: php

Let say I have image.jpg on my directory.

And assume that the only detail I know is that I have a filename which name = 'image' but i don't know what it's extension.

Is there a PHP function to know the extension of the file?

Comment: what happens if you have: image.jpg, image.gif and image.png?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the files with [`glob`](http://php.net/glob):

```
$matching = glob('/some/directory/' . $name . '.*');
```

Comment: That gives you all matching files, but not the extension (.jpg)

Comment: @user1933738: It's not hard to get the extension once you have the filenames. `end(explode('.', $filename))`, `pathinfo`, `FileInfo`, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php shows everything you need, path, filename and extension.